# powershell where-object -cnotmatch filter unwanted lines

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching, where-object

command

```
Get-Content -Path 'temp.cmd' | where { $_ -cnotmatch '^::|REM|rem'} | Set-Content 'temp1.cmd' -Encoding utf8
```

should filter-out comments from batch file. The 'REM', 'rem' and '::' on the beginning of lines. But if filter out lines like this

```
<nul set /p =%E%10;10fError: check log file
```

too. What could be wrong?

Comment: Try enclosing with `()` like this: `^(::|REM|rem)`. It will filter out only lines that start with what's in regex and not if it appears somewhere else in line. Not sure if it will solve your problem.

Comment: There could be executable files starting with `rem` that this would omit. Perhaps the regex pattern should be `'^\s*(::|REM|rem)\s+'`. Also, why is case sensitive used? What if the comment started with `Rem `?

Comment: In my scripts 'REM' used for persistent comment, but 'rem' for temporarily disabled functions. '::' is used for header descriptions. What function have this '\s*' and '\s+' strings??

Comment: This doesn't make sense unless there are two colons in the example.

Comment: The comment indicator, '::' or 'rem', might have whitespace at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @lit You are right, but this will require more complex regexp and in my code all coomment lines are start real beginning of lines.

Comment: So it's blocking lines that don't have REM or rem at the beginning?  What does that have to do with `<nul set /p =%E%10;10fError: check log file`?